# Interaction between two components

Tags: angular

I need some help.
I have a home page and a favourites page (another component)
In the home page the user enters a movie list and in this list it displays 2 buttons (Delete and fav)
My problem is in the fav
I want when I press the fav button it will add it to a favorites list and when I go to the favorite page it will display the favorites list.

Can you help me please?
I am a newbie in web programming.

My home.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-home', 
    templateUrl: './home.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'] 
}) 
export class HomeComponent { 
    /* Un tableau vide dans lequel vont être ajoutés les entrées.*/
    public films = [];
    public favorites = [];
  
    /* Ajout des élèments en entrée dans la liste avec vérification que le texte n'est pas vide.*/
    public newFilm; 
    public addToList() { 
        if (this.newFilm == '') { 
        } 
        else { 
            this.films.push(this.newFilm); 
            this.newFilm = ''; 
        } 
    } 
    /*Fonction permettant l'ajout d'un element à la liste des favoris*/
    public addtofav(index){
        this.favorites.push(this.newFilm);
    }
  
    /*Fonction permettant la suppression d'une élement de la liste des films et de favoris*/
    public deleteTask(index) { 
        this.films.splice(index, 1); 
        this.favorites.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

My home.component.html:

```
  <div class="row bg-dark justify-content-center 
          align-items-center" style="height:100px"> 
      <div class="col-5"></div> 
      <div class="col-6 text-white h2"> 
         Home Page
      </div> 
  </div>
  
  <!--Bloc s'occupant des inputs -->
  <div class="row mt-1" style="height:80px;"> 
    <div class="col-3 d-none col-md-3 d-md-block"></div> 
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-dark d-flex  
      justify-content-center align-items-center  
      text-light h3"> 
          <input [(ngModel)]="newFilm" type="text" 
                  value="" class="col-7 form-control"
                      style="width:300px;"> 

          <div class="col-1"></div> 

          <button (click)="addToList()"  
          class="btn btn-light text-danger"> 
              Ajoutez un film
          </button> 
      </div> 

      <div class="col-3 d-none col-md-3 d-md-block"></div> 
  </div> 

  <!--Bloc s'occupant de la liste des films-->
  <div *ngFor="let x of films; let index = index;" 
          class="row mt-1" style="height:100px;">

      <div class="col-3 d-none col-md-3 d-md-block"></div> 

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-dark d-flex 
                  justify-content-center align-items-center 
                  text-light h3"> 

          <div class="col-8 text-light h3">{{x}}</div> 

          <input (click)="deleteTask(index)" type="button"
              value="Delete" class="col-2 btn btn-danger"> 
          <input (click)="addtofav(index)" type = "button"
              value="Fav" class = "col-2 btn btn-success">
      </div>
        
      <div class="col-3 d-none col-md-3 d-md-block"></div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) can help you out, the page basically describes every possible method of component interactions. See what fits you best and if you run into any problems feel free to let us know.

Comment: Hi @MikeS. 
I already read this page. 
But I still don't know which interaction model used.
I don't think there is a parent-child relationship here, do I?
As you can see the favorites button is in the home page which displays the whole list of movies.
So I tried to create a second list in home.component.ts which saves the item each time I hit the favorites button in a list.
Now I want to display the favorites list in another page.
And I really don't know how to do it, I've been stuck on it for 2 days

Comment: It's pretty easy to find out, Parent/Child simply means that the component is nested into another component. Say you'd put `SomeOtherComponent` into the html of  `HomeComponent`, `SomeOtherComponent` would now be a `child` of `HomeComponent`, and `HomeComponent would be the parent`.

Comment: In your case, the favorite page is probably on another route(?), so your only way of communicating would be a shared service. Singleton services are basically single instances of a class that exist in your application and you can "inject" them into your components to access their properties (for example your stored favorites).

Comment: So I have to first create the routes before doing data sharing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding upon Mike S. answer.

You can share data between components if they are in a parent-child relation. You can also share data between them using services.

In your case it would be best to have a service with an observable array that your favourites component can subscribe to in order to get the list of favourites.

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }

  //you need to have an existing array in order to assing it to an observable one
  //since you cant directly push to ovbservable arrays
  private favouritesSource: string[] = [];
  favourites: Subject<string[]> = new Subject();

  addToFavourites(film: string){
    this.favouritesSource.push(film);
    this.favourites.next(this.favouritesSource);
  }
}
```

The favourites component:

```
export class FavouritesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  favourites: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    //assigning the array from the service to the one that displays the favourites
    this.sharedService.favourites.subscribe(favourites => {
      this.favourites = favourites;
    })
  }
}
```

The movies component:

```
export class MoviesComponent {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  addToFavourites(film: string){
    this.sharedService.addToFavourites(film);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps :)

### Edit

This approach will only work if both components are displayed at the same time which means that routing with this approach will not work.

This is because when you navigate using angulars router and display components using `router-outlet`, the component being displayed gets reloaded. This means that the `ngOnInit()` method gets called again and subsequently also the `.subscribe()` method of the observable.

The problem with that is that the statement inside the `.subscribe()` only fires once there was a change in the observable value and since the component which can initiate changes in the observable value isn't loaded in, the statment inside the `.subscribe()` doesn't fire.

### Edit 2

Here's the example if you have to navigate between the 2 components using angulars router.

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }

  private favourites: string[] = [];

  addToFavourites(film: string){
    this.favourites.push(film);
  }

  getFavourites(){
    return this.favourites;
  }
}
```

The movies component:

```
xport class MoviesComponent {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  addToFavourites(film: string){
    this.sharedService.addToFavourites(film);
  }
}
```

The favourites component:

```
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  favourites: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.favourites = this.sharedService.getFavourites();
  }

}
```

Navigation can occur like this:

```
constructor (private router: Router){}

this.router.navigate(['urlToNavigateTo']);
```

Or this:

```
<anyHtmlElement routerLink="/urlToNavigateTo">Navigate to url</anyHtmlElement>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4mtdyx?file=src%2Ffavourites%2Ffavourites.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is already helping me see a little more what to do.
However in your answer you add a movies component.
Except that I, in the home page, enter the films manually and they are added to a list which proposes to add them to favorites.
I'm not sure this can work in my case, right?

Comment: @MBToX92x just think of the movies component as your homepage component. Instead of having the array of favourites directly in you homepage component it would be inside the service where the favourites component also has access to it. So instead of adding it to the favourites array like you are doing now, you would add it to the array inside the service like I did in my example.

Comment: Okay
I'll try to do that and keep you posted.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: I just created the routes and did the service.
When I am on the Home page I type in the name of a movie which is added to the list that appears.
When I press the Add To Favorites button and then go to the favorites page nothing is displayed.
There isn't something to be done to make sure maybe when I change page and go from "localhost: 4200 / home" to "localhost: 4200 / favorites" that the data is kept?


THANK YOU

Comment: @MBToX92x I have made an edit to my original answer that tries to explain why it doesn't work for you. The solution would be to get the favourites from the service manually once the favourites component is loaded. You can do this by having a simple get method inside the service which returns the array of favourites and then call that method inside the favourites component's ngOnInit() method.
This only works if you navigate using angulars router and not if you enter the url manually into the browser and hit enter, since that reloads the whole page and clears all variables.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to do that. 
Currently I am trying to display the favorites because the code does not understand that when I press the Fav button it displays it on the favorites page (For the moment I put them on the same page both components)
Maybe you have a discord (or other platform) that I can send you my code to be more clearer for you?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @MBToX92x yeah I have discord. Send me your name and tag and I'll add you.